# Is the mapping that takes a metric to the induced intrinsic metric a closure operator?

Tags: metric-spaces

To abbreviate the expression, "it holds that," I will write "iht."

First a definition. Given a partially ordered set $(P,\geq)$, a closure operator on $P$ is a mapping $\mathrm{cl} : P \rightarrow P$ such that

1. (Idempotent) For all $d$ iht $\mathrm{cl}(\mathrm{cl}\,d) = \mathrm{cl} \,d.$
2. (Inflationary) For all $d$ iht $\mathrm{cl} \, d \geq d$
3. (Non-decreasing) For all $d,d'$ iht if $d \geq d'$, then $\mathrm{cl} \, d \geq \mathrm{cl} \, d'.$

Okay, upwards and onwards. Fix a set $X$, and let $P$ denote the set of all metrics $d$ on $X$. We will allow metrics to take values in $[0,\infty]$. So in particular, infinity is a valid distance. Now partially order $P$ by defining that for all $d,d' \in P$ iht $d \geq d'$ iff for all $x,y \in X$ iht $d(x,y) \geq d'(x,y)$. Finally, let $\mathrm{cl} : P \rightarrow P$ denote the mapping that takes a metric to the [induced intrinsic metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric). Is $\mathrm{cl}$ a closure operator?

If so, I believe this means that path metric spaces (that is, metric spaces that agree with their induced intrinsic metric) form a complete lattice. The question is then: do any distributive laws hold in this lattice?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/132404 for a proof of the fact that cl is idempotent *provided* that $d$ has rectifiable paths connecting any two points. It is then clear that for such metrics cl is a closure operator.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by t.b.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/132480/) pointed out by [jim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349001/is-the-mapping-that-takes-a-metric-to-the-induced-intrinsic-metric-a-closure-ope#comment750378_349001) assumed the space rectifiably connected, because metric spaces there were understood in the usual way, with finite metric. If finiteness is not required, neither is being rectifiably connected. The operator $\mathrm{cl}$ is indeed idempotent.

I don't understand the lattice part. We have the join operation on path metrics, namely $\operatorname{cl}\max(d,d')$. But what is the meet?